# How to start one bash script from another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, command-line-interface

I'm trying to keep a long-running php cli process running on Centos 7, with little success.
So I'm resorting to a couple of bash scripts - one to start the process, and another to check the process is running, and restart it if it isn't. The restart script is fired every two minutes by cron.

This is my cron entry

`*/2 * * * * bash /var/www/html/production/start_process.sh`

Here are my two scripts

**start_process.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if ps -f | grep -q "[p]rocess_queue" ; then echo "Message queue process is already running" ; else bash /var/www/html/production/process_message_queue.sh; fi
```

**process_message_queue.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting process message queue"
nohup php /var/www/html/production/index.php messages process_queue > process_message_queue.out 2> process_message_queue.err < /dev/null &
echo "Started process message queue"
```

Each script, when run via the terminal, behaves as expected.

`bash start_process.sh` will either return a message that the process is running, or will fire the second script, which will correctly start the PHP process.

When running from cron, however, the first script will start, and will fire the second. I know this, because the 2 echoed statements appear in /var/spool/mail/root.
But if I execute `ps -f` after the cron job has fired, the process isn't there.

I have full paths to each shell script, the cron is root, and each shell script is owned by root.

Comment: Are you expecting to see the shell script in the process? Once it's executed the command it'll close the script / shell unless it's a live process).

Comment: I'm expecting to see the php script - it's a permanent loop that I have nohupped and sent to the background.

Comment: Anything at all in the `process_message_queue.out/err` files? A simple explanation would be that the process spawned by php exits nearly immediately because of an error, which could happen for instance if it relies on environment variables that aren't set in the context of the cronjob

Comment: no, they're empty, which is also puzzling. I did previously have env errors due to missing globals, but resolved these, as evidenced (I believe) by the fact that I can execute both shell scripts via the terminal, and the process stays running in the background.

Comment: Can you not put some debug statements in? e.g. echo `date` > /tmp/start.txt etc. and see where it's actually getting to? Running it from your shell doesn't necessarily mean it's the same as cron - for example if running from Cron you might need to cd to the dir / use full paths (whereas your shell will have them preserved). You say you're certain it's running, but I'd argue that may not be the case. Perhaps put some steps before and after the php call, and don't run via nohup - why not just background the process - for example? or redirect the process log to another file for debugging?

Comment: I put the final ```echo "Started process message queue"``` to check that it got the end of the second script, and that line shows up in /var/spool/mail/root, which led me to believe it was making it all the way to the end. I've got full paths in each of the two scripts as well. I'll try it without the nohup...

Comment: You don't have the path to `php` !

Answer (score 1):

Aside from fixing the underlying issue with your PHP command (and why it crashes), I would recommend wrapping this behaviour as a service instead of a cron job. This has the added benefit of immediate restart on failure (as opposed to cron, where you would have to wait until the next minute). For example, if you're using systemd, you can add the following service (`/etc/systemd/system/charliefortune.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=CharlieFortuneService
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/var/www/html/production/process_message_queue.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And change `process_message_queue.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting process message queue"
php /var/www/html/production/index.php messages process_queue > process_message_queue.out 2> process_message_queue.err  # This blocks
echo "Started process message queue"
```

You would also get some nice logging output in your service manager

I realise this is more of a comment than an answer, but I lack the reputation to comment on your question.

Comment: This is good, thanks. I was aware that my approach was flawed, I got to this solution out of desperation to solve a problem, really.